# node which port / ip address to listen to for azure ubuntu vm

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, azure, dns, azure-virtual-machine

I've got an Ubuntu virtual machine on Azure. I added an enpoint in the azure management portal:

```
NAME   PROTOCOL   PUBLIC PORT   PRIVATE PORT  LOAD-BALANCED SET
---------------------------------------------------------------
HTTP   TCP        80            80            -
```

And I tried to listen to it:

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.end("Hello World\n");
});

server.listen(80);
```

It works if I ssh in and curl it:

```
$ curl localhost:80
Hello World
```

But if I try to access it by `subdomain.cloudapp.net`, nothing comes back. It also doesn't return anything when accessed by public ip address.

Which port and address should I listen on with my node application to access it from the outside world?

Do I need another azure service to be able to access the VM?

How would I enable public access if it's a problem with the firewall?

---

Edit:

I checked if there was a firewall, but there isn't:

```
$ sudo ufw status
[out :: subdomain.cloudapp.net] Status: inactive
```

Edit 2:

Provisioned a different ubuntu vm, but it still doesn't work. Tried to restart iptables, but no service was known:

```
$ sudo service iptables restart
iptables: unrecognized service
```

The iptables are:

```
$ sudo iptables -L

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:http


Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination


Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that port 80 is open in your VM's firewall (iptables)?

Comment: How would I confirm that? (very new here to server stuff)

Comment: @DavidMakogon still have no idea how to allow outside access, not sure if it's supposed to use an ACL?

Comment: Try access port 80 on the private IP address of your VM - use ifconfig to see what IPs are bound to your machine and then try hit port 80 on the applicable 10.*.*.* one.  Your VM is on an internal network and theoretically knows nothing about the *.cloudapp.net address which is bound to the cloud service that wraps your VM (and on which you setup the endpoint).

Comment: Other than setting an endpoint for port 80 (as you have done already ) you shouldn't need to do anything. As long as you run "sudo node server.js" on your box and hit it from a browser it should work OK. This might be silly, but you are NOT closing the terminal, right? Also, you might consider creating a new VM just to be sure you start from scratch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't know what's wrong with your sample.
Here is my sequence of steps which works:

1. Create 'Extra Small' Ubuntu Server 13.10 instance in WestUS. (NEW->Virtual Machine->Quick Create)
2. Add endpoint HTTP 80 -> 80  (Endpoints->Add->Add New Standalone Endpoint->HTTP,TCP,80,80)
3. Install nodejs (sudo apt-get install nodejs). This installs version 'v0.10.15'
4. Create server.js with your code.
5. Start nodejs server (sudo nodejs server.js)

I'm able to connect remotely via ndtest2.cloudapp.net name(already deleted) and get "Hello World".

EDIT:
However I cannot connect to the version built from sources.
But I can connect if I download binaries from http://nodejs.org

Comment: ah. which apt-get nodejs do you use? I did the following: `add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js`. should i not do that?

Comment: I don't specify which to use. Just do 'sudo apt-get install nodejs' on clean vm.

Answer (score 3):

You are probobly listening on `127.0.0.1`, or local host. You need to be listening on `0.0.0.0`, to fix this, replace

```
server.listen(80);
```

with

```
server.listen(80, "0.0.0.0")
```

Just to clarify, `0.0.0.0` is not an acutal address, it means all addresses, 127.0.0.1 and any other IPs.

Comment: When I try that I get `curl: (7)  Failed connect to 0.0.0.0:80 Connection rufused`

Comment: I tried localhost, 127.0.0.1, 0.0.0.0, public vm ip, private vm ip all with no success :(

Comment: This worked for me. I set the ran the server under port 4000 and the host as 0.0.0.0. When an endpoint is setup to send 80 -> 4000 like Sergey Zyuzin says about then it worked fine.

Comment: This helped me out! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

With azure you need to use the environment variable process.env.PORT to set the port. 
If on localhost you want to use the 80, a good way to set it in your code in this way as recommended [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/tutorials/getting-started/):

```
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 80);
```

However, be sure, if you run a VM on Azure, [that the windows firewall is correctly set](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/28100eb3-6e9b-4012-a273-84062f4e293a/azure-firewall-how-to-allow-outbound-and-inbound-traffic-on-vm?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows).

Comment: I've set the port and it's listening correctly. The problem is I can't access the VM from the outside world.

Comment: You're missing the point of the answerer.  You need to listen on the specific port that you are told (via process.env.PORT).  You cannot listen on whatever port you like.

Comment: @AJcodez You already got the answer. Open the terminal and run this: sudo PORT=80 node server.js

Comment: @batbaatar it's not a Website, its on a VM. The server is listening, that's not the problem. I just can't access it from the outside world! When I SSH in the server responds correctly. But when I put the public IP address into my browser, nothing comes back.

Comment: If the endpoint is done, protocol TCP, ports 80 both, it is not visible because.....you need to configure the windows firewall. Open the 80 and will be fine :)

Comment: @matteofigus I can't stress it enough that it's an ubuntu vm, so I doubt there's a windows firewall. In the discussion it says `Connectivity does not seem to be enabled. I do have an application listening on this port at the server.` so i think a lot of ppl are struggling with this!

Comment: @AJcodez then try disabling the firewall. Then we will know if it is a firewall issue or not. Just ssh your Azure VM and run this command: sudo ufw disable

Answer (score 1):

I believe your port is not allowing remote connection on port 80 as you can get into the ubuntu VM using ssh tunneling from outside. Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19569280/1426743) . Though it's apache related , but this two problem looks alike and it's actually identical. Try this out.

In the mean time , best of luck. Fingers crossed :p