# Accessing Apache Server from a remote machine

Tags: apache, rhel

I am using Red Hat 4.4.7-4 . I have installed Apache Server using

yum install httpd

/etc/init.d/httpd start

/etc/init.d/httpd status
httpd (pid  1371) is running...

This machine can be accesses through a VPN client using ssh terminal. When I hit

```
http://ip address:80
```

in a browser, the page doesnt load. I get the following error:

```
This Page Cannot Be Displayed

The system cannot communicate with the external server ( 173.39.232.226 ). The Internet server may be busy, may be permanently down, or may be unreachable because of network problems.

Please check the spelling of the Internet address entered. If it is correct, try this request later.

If you have questions, or feel this is an error, please contact your corporate network administrator and provide the codes shown below.
Notification codes:     (1, GATEWAY_TIMEOUT, 173.39.232.226)
```

Also, below is the output of iptables

```
[root@blended-services-demo html]# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Answer (score 0):

You probalby need to enable access to your server on port 80 as it is currently being blocked by iptables.

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

This will insert the rule into your iptables configuration at the start. Once you have done this and tested that it works then you should save the configuration so that it it is used next time the service starts,

```
sudo /sbin/service iptables save
```

this will write the current configuration to /etc/sysconfig/iptables.

if this dont solve your problem, i suggest you take a look here:
[apache not accepting incoming connections from outside of localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729247/apache-not-accepting-incoming-connections-from-outside-of-localhost)

Comment: I took a look at the link, but it still doesnt solve my problem. I have edited my post to include the output of iptables