# Not able to access apache server on centos using ip address

Tags: linux, apache, centos, webserver

I am trying to setup a remote apache server on centos. I have installed httpd and it is listening to port 80 as it is supposed to. And I am able to connect to the remote system through ssh. but when I try to access the apache server on website using the ip address browser is giving 'Could not connect to error".

My iptable looks like this

[image: iptable]

I have tried solutions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729247/apache-not-accepting-incoming-connections-from-outside-of-localhost) question and none of them are working.

Comment: Run `netstat -anp|grep :80` to see what IP Apache is bound to.  Also confirm that you do not have a firewall or NAT blocking access.

Answer (score 0):

Could you have something using NAT in between ? If yes then you have to configure port forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

If you disabled the SELinux using:

```
setenforce 0
```

then your server may be behind a firewall, or NAT, and port 80 need to be enabled there.