# Rails app on Apache-Passenger - runs fine on localhost but not via remote access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ruby-on-rails-4, centos, passenger

I have a Rails application deployed on Apache-Passenger which runs fine when access from localhost, but doesn't run via remote access.

Let's say the server name is `server.name.com`. The server info is -

```
[kbc@server KBC]$ uname -a
Linux server.name.com 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Nov 22 03:15:09 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[kbc@server KBC]$ cat /etc/issue
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
Kernel \r on an \m
```

When I do
`[kbc@server ]$ curl http://localhost:3000/`, it returns the home page for the application.

But when I try to access the Rails app from my laptop, I get the following error -

```
→ curl http://server.name.com:3000/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to server.name.com port 3000: Connection refused
```

To check if I can access the server, I tried -

```
→ ping server.name.com:3000
ping: cannot resolve server.name.com:3000: Unknown host
```

But, I can ping the server by -

```
→ ping server.name.com
PING server.name.com (@.@.@.@): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from @.@.@.@: icmp_seq=0 ttl=61 time=1.526 ms
64 bytes from @.@.@.@: icmp_seq=1 ttl=61 time=6.624 ms
```

Here is the Passenger configuration -

```
<VirtualHost *:3000>
   ServerName server.name.com
   ServerAlias server.name.com
   DocumentRoot /home/kbc/KBC/public
   <Directory /home/kbc/KBC/public>
      AllowOverride all
      Options -MultiViews
   </Directory>
  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/kbc_error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/kbc_access.log common
</VirtualHost>

NameVirtualHost *:3000
PassengerPreStart https://server.name.com:3000/
```

and

```
LoadModule passenger_module /home/kbc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@kbc/gems/passenger-5.0.30/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
        PassengerRoot /home/kbc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@kbc/gems/passenger-5.0.30
        PassengerDefaultRuby /home/kbc/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.3.0/ruby
        PassengerRuby /home/kbc/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.3.0/ruby
        PassengerMaxPoolSize 5
        PassengerPoolIdleTime 90
        PassengerMaxRequests 10000
</IfModule>
```

Passenger-status info -

```
[kbc@server ]$ passenger-status
Version : 5.0.30
Date    : 2016-10-17 11:30:08 -0400
Instance: bKUJ0ptp (Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 Phusion_Passenger/5.0.30)

----------- General information -----------
Max pool size : 5
App groups    : 1
Processes     : 1
Requests in top-level queue : 0

----------- Application groups -----------
/home/kbc/KBC:
  App root: /home/kbc/KBC
  Requests in queue: 0
  * PID: 5696    Sessions: 0       Processed: 1       Uptime: 1m 45s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 38M     Last used: 1m 45s ago
```

What am I doing wrong? Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a connectivity problem, not a Passenger/Apache problem.  The host you're running the server on may not accept inbound connections on port 3000 (due to iptables, firewall, or security group access control rules).

Take a look at [apache not accepting incoming connections from outside of localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729247/apache-not-accepting-incoming-connections-from-outside-of-localhost) and [Apache VirtualHost and localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981174/apache-virtualhost-and-localhost), for instance.

Answer (score 1):

@Jatin, could you please post the apache main configuration ? (/etc/apache2/apache2.conf or similar)

Also, please provide the output of the following :

```
sudo netstat -nl
sudo iptables -L
```

Just for the record, the **ping** utility can only test connectivity at the **IP layer**, meaning that it can tell you whether the host at a given IP is responding. It cannot, however, tell you if a specific TCP port is open on the remote system.

Testing TCP connectivity can be achieved easily with **telnet** or **netcat** :

```
telnet server.name.com 3000
```

If you get something like :

```
Trying @.@.@.@...
Connected to server.name.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

then this means you can correctly access the TCP endpoint, eliminating any possibility of network-related issues. In other words, if this works, you probably have a configuration problem with Apache.